# all selected items unchecked when unchecking other items in listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, checkbox

```
For Each i As ListViewItem In Me.lvSent.Items

            If i.Checked = True Then
                i.Selected = True
            Else
                i.Selected = False

            End If
        Next
```

Using that code I can select items in my listview but when I unchecked one selected item, It unchecked all selected items.

How can I uncheck other selected item without unchecking everything

thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using the "ItemChecked" event, I was able to reproduce. I dont have an answer but it might make you feel better that you're not crazy. Strange behavior indeed.

Comment: thanks sir.... I'm aware of that...